# Cancelling Bluebirds Promise.all when fetched x items

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, bluebird, cancellation

I'm trying to fetch X number of in stock items, and once I have them I don't want to fetch anymore. Here's my code so far:

```
const numberOfInstockItemsToShow = 10;

let inStockCount = 0;

let cancellablePromise;

const promises = data.map((item) => {
    return fetch(url, options).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
        }
    }).then((d) => {
        inStockCount++;

        if (inStockCount >= numberOfInstockItemsToShow) {
            cancellablePromise.cancel();
        }
        return d;
    });
});

cancellablePromise = Promise.all(promises).then((d) => {
  console.log("all the files were created:", d);
});
```

I've set the cancellation to true in the config, so am thinking it's something related to my dodgy code.

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with you cancel the promise and what do you observe happening that is different than that?  According to the Bluebird doc, what canceling a promise does is keeps its `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers from being called.  It doesn't actually cancel any underlying async operation.  In the case of `Promise.all()`, it doesn't affect the promises that it is monitoring, only the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers for the master promise that `Promise.all()` returned.

Comment: So, if what you were hoping to do is to abort any further `fetch()` calls once you find an `inStockCount` that is high enough, then `.cancel()` is not going to help you at all.  All the other ajax calls have already been sent and using `.cancel()` on the master promise doesn't affect them at all.  So, all that happens is you won't get any result out of `Promise.all()` because you cancelled it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Not the answer I was hoping for, but saves me wasting any more time on this approach. Thanks or your help!

Comment: Do you want to sequence the `fetch()` calls so you can do one, examine its result and then decide whether to go to the next one or not?

Comment: Thats what I'm doing so far, and am using a recursion function for that. However I'd like to run them asynchronously otherwise it's a bit slow doing it one at a time.

Comment: Well, you kind of have to decide.  You either run them serially so you can stop when you want or you run them in parallel and they are all started already so you can't undo that when you realize you're done.  The only in-between solution would be running them N at a time.  You could use the concurrency option with `Promise.map()` for that and you can get it to stop by rejecting with a specific value you can test for when you realize you're done.  If you want me to show you that in an answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the info @jfriend00. That's so far the best option I have I believe

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.some([...], count)`. The first argument is an array and second is a number of resolved promises to consider as fulfilled. [Reference](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html)

```
const numberOfInstockItemsToShow = 10;

const promises = data.map((item) => {
    return fetch(url, options).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
        }
    });
});

Promise.some(promises, numberOfInstockItemsToShow).then((d) => {
  console.log("all the files were created:", d);
});
```

Please note that this will not cancel any further promises after reaching the `count`. This will simply fulfill as soon as the required number of promises are resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @abskmj, but like you mentioned it will not cancel the remaining fetches. This half solves my issue, but not fully.